# URL RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im trying to rewrite my urls and I have the following in my htaccess where the pageid is the mysql id for each page and title is the page title.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ content.php?pageid=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

**Current URL structure based on this rule is:**
http://domian.com/3/Contact.html

**And would like to change it to:**
http://domian.com/Contact.html

Also I have this php function that changes the URL:

```
  function createPageLink($id)
  {
      global $db, $core;

      $sql = "SELECT id, slug FROM pages WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'";
      $row = $db->first($sql);

      $slug = $row['slug'];

      if ($core->seo == 1) {
          $display = $core->site_url . '/' . intval($id) . '/' . sanitize($slug) . '.html';
      } else {
          $display = $core->site_url . '/content.php?pageid=' . intval($id);
      }
      return $display;
  }
```

So basically remove the number after the URL and just have the title only.

I know its pretty simple but it driving me nuts. Thanks

Comment: Is the pageid no longer necessary or should it be hardcoded in the rewrite?

Comment: No I no longer need the page ID as its unnecessary ...it just came with the CMS.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeking this,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ content.php?title=$1 [L]
```

The following will match both.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)?/?([^\/]*)\.html$ content.php?pageid=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

When I test it following files were used.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)?/?([^\/]*)\.html$ index.php?part1=$1&part2=$2 [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

index.php file to test.

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
```

Comment: I have it like this ....should it go inside this or outside <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ content.php?pageid=$1&title=$2 [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: I added the code above but its giving me the number and if I just go to the url itself it redirects me to the homepage..

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the database ?

Comment: No you dont have to do anything  in database. Check my samples again. You need to modify it. Specially `index.php?part1=$1&part2=$2` part.

Comment: @Dony If it redirects then its your script that does the redirection. Fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need make some tokens for each page. For instance: token Contact refer to id 1. You can do it with arrays, for instance, or a `switch`.

**Example for PHP**:

```
$token_ids = new array();
$token_ids['Home'] = 1;
$token_ids['Contact'] = 2;

$current_token = $_GET['title']; // following your example

if(!isset($token_ids[$current_token])) {
  // ERROR or REDIRECT like to home:
  $current_token = 'Home';
}

// similar to $_GET['pageid'] of example
$current_token_id = $tokens_id[$current_token];
```

You can do it on MySQL too, simply you need save an unique token for each page. Like:

```
id | token     | page_title
1    Home        Hello!
2    Contact     Contact us!
```

Comment: I have already done this. I am just trying to remove the ID though so its cleaner.

Comment: Do you want to redirect /3/Contact.html to /Contact.html? Or just accept /Contact.html instead of /3/Contact.html?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, if you really don't need the id, you could simply do the following (don't forget to clean the title before you search the db though):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ content.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: No I dont need the the id at all but I tried your solution and didnt work.

Comment: So do I need to delete all the IDs and then apply this rule ?

Comment: @Dony Are the client requests still including the ID or not?  If you don't need them, remove them - and then this should work

Comment: <div id="mainmenu">
      <?php $mainmenu = $content->getMenuList(); $content->getMenu($mainmenu,0);?>
    </div>

Comment: I have a dabase table called page_id

Comment: @Dony can you elaborate on how the above didn't work? (ie. does it go to content.php and what are the $_GET parameters when it gets there?)